# Finding the first and last business day for every month sql

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2016

I am trying to find the first and last business day for every month since 1986. 
Using this, I can find the first day of any given month using, but just that month and it does not take into consideration whether it is a business day or not. To make it easier for now, business day is simply weekdays and does not consider public holiday.

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate()),0))
```

But I am not able to get the correct business day, so I created a calendar table consisting of all the weekdays and thought that I can extract the min(date) from each month, but I am currently stuck.

```
Date
---------------
1986-01-01
1986-01-02
1986-01-03
1986-01-06
...and so on
```

I have tried to get the first day of every month instead, but it does not take into account whether the day is a weekend or not. It just simply give the first day of each month

```
declare @DatFirst date = '20000101', @DatLast date = getdate();
declare @DatFirstOfFirstMonth date = dateadd(day,1-day(@DatFirst),@DatFirst);
select  DatFirstOfMonth = dateadd(month,n,@DatFirstOfFirstMonth)
from    (select  top (datediff(month,@DatFirstOfFirstMonth,@DatLast)+1)
            n=row_number() over (order by (select 1))-1
    from    (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) a (n)
    cross join (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) b (n)
    cross join (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) c (n)
    cross join (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) d (n)
    ) x
```

I am wondering if anyone can perhaps shed some light as to how can I best approach this issue.

Comment: Please explain what day you consider as business day ?

Comment: What is your business day? Do you want to consider public holiday too?

Comment: @AmithKumar business day here is defined by a day where the stock market is trading. 
Let's not worry about public holiday at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got already a table with all the weekdays only:

```
select min(datecol), max(datecol)
from BusinessOnlyCalendar
group by year(datecol), month(datecol)
```

But you should expand your calendar to include all those calculations you might do on date, like FirstDayOfWeek/Month/Quarter/Year, WeekNumber, etc.

When you got a column in your calendar indicating *business day yes/no*, it's a simple:

```
select min(datecol), max(datecol)
from calendar
where businessday = 'y'
group by year(datecol), month(datecol)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have your calendar table with all available dates, then you just need to filter by weekday.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- 1: Monday, 7: Sunday

SELECT
    Year = YEAR(T.Date),
    Month = MONTH(T.Date),
    FirstBusinessDay = MIN(T.Date),
    LastBusinessDay = MAX(T.Date)
FROM
    Calendar AS T
WHERE
    DATEPART(WEEKDAY, T.Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 -- 1: Monday, 5: Friday
GROUP BY
    YEAR(T.Date),
    MONTH(T.Date)
```

You should use the query to mark these days on your calendar table, so it's easy to access them afterwards.

---

This is how you can mix it up with the generation of the calendar table (with recursion).

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- 1: Monday, 7: Sunday

declare 
    @DatFirst date = '20000101', 
    @DatLast date = getdate();

;WITH AllDays AS
(
    SELECT
        Date = @DatFirst

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, D.Date)
    FROM
        AllDays AS D
    WHERE
        D.Date < @DatLast
),
BusinessLimitsByMonth AS
(
    SELECT
        Year = YEAR(T.Date),
        Month = MONTH(T.Date),
        FirstBusinessDay = MIN(T.Date),
        LastBusinessDay = MAX(T.Date)
    FROM
        AllDays AS T
    WHERE
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, T.Date) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 -- 1: Monday, 5: Friday
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(T.Date),
        MONTH(T.Date)
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    BusinessLimitsByMonth AS B
ORDER BY
    B.Year,
    B.Month
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 0) -- 0: Unlimited
```